# React / CSS : Nightmode button that dosnt changes my navbar background color

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new on React. I just added a theme color to my page.

**Everything goes from black to white and vice versa when I click my button "Change Theme".**

**But .. the navbar that was initially lightblue colored, isnt changing !**

That navbar is the only element that isnt changed by my button " Change Theme ".

I dont quite clearly understand, because the body color was supposed to be changed.
Im really bad at CSS.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './Pages/About';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Works from './Pages/Works';
import PageNotFound from './Pages/PageNotFound';
import StudyCase from './Pages/StudyCase';
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { lightTheme, darkTheme, GlobalStyles } from './Components/Themes';

const StyledApp = styled.div`

  color: ${props => props.theme.fontColor}

`;

function App() {

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light')

  const themeToggler = () => {
    theme === 'light' ? setTheme("dark") : setTheme("light");
  }


  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme === 'light' ? lightTheme : darkTheme} >
      <GlobalStyles />
      <StyledApp>
      <Router>
    
// NAVBAR
    <div style={{width: 100 + "vw", height: 80, backgroundColor: "lightblue"}}>

      <button onClick={() => themeToggler()}>Change Theme</button>
      <Link to="/" style={{margin: 50}}>Home</Link>
      <Link to="/works" style={{margin: 50}}>Projets</Link>
      <Link to="/about" >L'agence</Link>
    
    </div>
// END OF NAVBAR

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
      <Route path="/works" exact component={Works} />
      <Route path="/works/:name-study-case" exact component={StudyCase} />
      <Route path="*" exact component={PageNotFound} />
    </Switch>

  </Router>
  </StyledApp>
  </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Themes.js**

```
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components';

export const lightTheme = {
 body: "#fff",
 fontColor: "#000"
}

export const darkTheme = {
 body: "#000",
 fontColor: "#fff"
}

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`

 body {
   background-color: ${props => props.theme.body}
 }

`
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the styling "manually" here:

```
style={{width: 100 + "vw", height: 80, backgroundColor: "lightblue"}
```

That will always override your theme stylesheet due to CSS precedence rules. Get rid of that and it should all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is Pass Object in style?

```
    let styles = {
        backgoungColor: "red;
    }
    return(<div style={styles}></div>);
```